# How to create on click event for children in Expandable list

Tags: android, events, listener

I am playing around with this example.
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.html

I cannot figure out how to attach a listener to the children elements so that I can trigger some action when the user taps on the phone number.

Any code or links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to subscribe to [setOnChildClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

```
getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(this);
```

and implement OnChildClickListener

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
        int childPosition, long id) {
    // use groupPosition and childPosition to locate the current item in the adapter
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does this apply to the example I linked to?
It seems like that example does not implement ExpandableListView

Comment: Sure it does as it extends `ExpandableListActivity`

Comment: Thank you.
Would you happen to know what's the proper way of getting the value or "label" of the clicked child?

Comment: You need to use the two int values to jump in the right position of the adapter(s) and get the value from it. Check the cursor you have methods to `moveToPosition(pos)`, then you simply get values from the cursor.

Comment: How do we determine the group position without having to manually compare to a value? because my expandable list view will have up to a 100 elements with each childclicklistener calling a different URL.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify location of items in expandable list like this

```
listView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int group_position, int child_position, long id)
    {
        if(group_position==0 && child_position==0){
            TryFragment secondFragment = (TryFragment) SampleActivity.this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tryFragment);
            secondFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if(group_position==2 && child_position==2){
            TryFragment secondFragment = (TryFragment) SampleActivity.this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tryFragment);
            secondFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should override [onChildClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html#onChildClick%28android.widget.ExpandableListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20long%29) in your ExpandableListActivity extension.

Comment: how do i get the selected child after overriding?