# How can i add action to each child in an expandable list?

Tags: android, eclipse

Here is my code.This is kinda noob question.how can I add action to a child in list view .
This code contains an expandable list view whit 3 children and what I need is when I click on each child separately it opens another class  like page2.java.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;

public class ExpandableListDemo extends ExpandableListActivity {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
        new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                createGroupList(),              // Creating group List.
                R.layout.group_row,             // Group item layout XML.           
                new String[] { "Group Item" },  // the key of group item.
                new int[] { R.id.row_name },    // ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.                   
                createChildList(),              // childData describes second-level entries.
                R.layout.child_row,             // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
                new String[] {"Sub Item"},      // Keys in childData maps to display.
                new int[] { R.id.grp_child}     // Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
            );
        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );       // setting the adapter in the list.

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/* Creating the Hashmap for the row */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createGroupList() {
      ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
      for( int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; ++i ) { // 15 groups........
        HashMap m = new HashMap();
        m.put( "Group Item","Group Item " + i ); // the key and it's value.
        result.add( m );
      }
      return (List)result;
}

/* creatin the HashMap for the children */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createChildList() {

    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; ++i ) { // this -15 is the number of groups(Here it's fifteen)
      /* each group need each HashMap-Here for each group we have 3 subgroups */
      ArrayList secList = new ArrayList(); 
      for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n++ ) {
        HashMap child = new HashMap();
        child.put( "Sub Item", "Sub Item " + n );           
        secList.add( child );
      }
     result.add( secList );
    }        
    return result;
}
public void  onContentChanged  () {
    System.out.println("onContentChanged");
    super.onContentChanged();         
}
/* This function is called on each child click */
public boolean onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id) {
    System.out.println("Inside onChildClick at groupPosition = " + groupPosition +" Child clicked at position " + childPosition);
    return true;
}

/* This function is called on expansion of the group */
public void  onGroupExpand  (int groupPosition) {
    try{
         System.out.println("Group exapanding Listener => groupPosition = " + groupPosition);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(" groupPosition Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [onChildClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

- Look at this post for [how to implement onChildClick()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3416843/1626878).
- Also look at [Adding listener to child nodes in Expandable List Item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8589469/1626878).